# Is it Possible to make a button as File upload Button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, file-upload

I am new in php. I have a form on which i place a button Value as `Upload MB` when user click on this button it redirects on a web form where i place a file upload control and user upload file here. 
Here is image

[image: button]

After clicking this button user redirect on this form

[image: upload form]

here user upload file.

**MY QUESTION**

Is it possible that can i make my button `Upload Mb` as file upload button? Can it works like file upload control button?

Actually i want to save user time. I want that when user click on `Upload MB` button it not redirects on Form. But when user Click on `Upload MB` button it allow to user to upload file and open browsing window. After that when user upload file it redirects on form.

Can you guys tell me it is possible or not?

Comment: why don't you keep your **file upload** control in the place of **upload MB**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao acyully i want to save user time, I want that user direct upload file without going on form

Comment: Its quite confusing @sunny!! You want to save user time so you dont wanna redirect!! and my suggestion was to replace `Upload MB` with `file upload` control!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Thank you for your suggestion. Please look at Shrinivas Answer below. Actully i want that function which is in answer. After that fuction i want to redirect user on Form

Comment: once user selects the file you want to redirect? or once uploaded to server?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes when user select his file then he redirects on form

Comment: If you do so you will loose the file content!! you have to upload it before redirecting!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao is there any way can i carry my file content while redirection with url?

Comment: you can use `localStorage` in that case. Here is one **[link](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/)** to understand how!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can keep a `<input type='file' hidden/>` in your code and click it using javascript when the user clicks on the **`"Upload MB"`** button.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/m0trsgct/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', openDialog);

function openDialog() {
  document.getElementById('fileid').click();
}
```

```html
<input id='fileid' type='file' hidden/>
<input id='buttonid' type='button' value='Upload MB' />
```

Here is the complete code.

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <script>
            function setup() {
                document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', openDialog);
                function openDialog() {
                    document.getElementById('fileid').click();
                }
                document.getElementById('fileid').addEventListener('change', submitForm);
                function submitForm() {
                    document.getElementById('formid').submit();
                }
            }
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body onload="setup()">
        <form id='formid' action="form.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <input id='fileid' type='file' name='filename' hidden/>
            <input id='buttonid' type='button' value='Upload MB' /> 
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' /> 
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Shrinivas How it will redirect on form after upload file?

Comment: Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/m0trsgct/2/). You just need to enclose your form controls inside `form` tag.

Comment: did it carry file while redirection?

Comment: Absolutely, form submission transfers all the values to the server during redirection. On the server, these values can be accessed using their `name` attribute, `'filename'` in this case.

Comment: But when i run this code in my browser as my php file upload button is not working

Comment: din not open browsing window\

Comment: Check console for errors. If it is working on stackoverflow as well as on jsfiddle, then it should also work on your browser. There must be some error in the console.

Comment: Can it is possible without using submit button i redirect user?

Comment: When user choose file then without clicking on submit button it redirect on form?

Comment: Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/m0trsgct/3/). Use javascript to submit the form when user selects the file. No need to click **`"Submit"`** button

Comment: Why all fiddle is not working when i paste it in my page?

Comment: Check for these 2 main reasons (1) There is **NO** `html` tag , `body` tag in fiddle. Add it before copying it to your code (2) Place the javascript part inside `script` tag in the `head` tag.

Comment: `<html>
<head>
<script>
document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', openDialog);
function openDialog() {
    document.getElementById('fileid').click();}
document.getElementById('fileid').addEventListener('change', submitForm);
function submitForm() {
    document.getElementById('formid').submit();}</script>
</head><body><form id='formid' action="form.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id='fileid' type='file' name='filename' hidden/><input id='buttonid' type='button' value='Upload MB' />
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Check out my updated answer. [Here](https://jsbin.com/pabiyi/edit?html,output) is the entire code.

Answer (score 13):

my 2 cents to the topic: all in code, no input needs to be added to the page.

```js
function onClickHandler(ev) {
  var el = window._protected_reference = document.createElement("INPUT");
  el.type = "file";
  el.accept = "image/*";
  el.multiple = "multiple"; // remove to have a single file selection
  
  // (cancel will not trigger 'change')
  el.addEventListener('change', function(ev2) {
    // access el.files[] to do something with it (test its length!)
    
    // add first image, if available
    if (el.files.length) {
      document.getElementById('out').src = URL.createObjectURL(el.files[0]);
    }


    // test some async handling
    new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(function() { console.log(el.files); resolve(); }, 1000);
    })
    .then(function() {
      // clear / free reference
      el = window._protected_reference = undefined;
    });

  });

  el.click(); // open
}
```

```css
#out {
  width: 100px; height: 100px; object-fit: contain; display: block;
}

/* hide if it would show the error img */
#out[src=''] {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="" id="out" />
<button onClick="onClickHandler(event)">select an IMAGE</button>
```

Note: the `el` might get garbage collected, before you process all data - adding it to `window.*` will keep the reference alive for any Promise-handling.

Comment: Cleanest of all

Comment: Out of curiosity, when would the change event fire but files be empty? Your comment "*test its length!*" seems reasonable but I'm trying to understand when this would ever happen.

Comment: @Butthosenewbuttonsthough.. If I call correctly, the change event fires when closing the dialog by pressing "ok" without having selected any file when "mutliple" is set.

Comment: Ok - maybe a Windows behaviour.  In my browser on OS X, the button is "Open" and it's disabled unless something is selected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest to convert button to label. apply the css to label so that it looks like button.

e.g. -

```
        <input type="file" id="BtnBrowseHidden" name="files" style="display: none;" />
        <label for="BtnBrowseHidden" id="LblBrowse">
            Browse
        </label>
```

Comment: This doesn't work from an accessibility standpoint - keyboard-only users will not be able to open your file input since the label cannot receive focus. Making the label into a button won't work either: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Accessibility_concerns.

It's unfortunate because this is a really clean solution otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap Way

```css
.choose_file {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;   
    font: normal 14px Myriad Pro, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #7f7f7f;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background: white
}
.choose_file input[type="file"]{
    -webkit-appearance:none; 
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="choose_file">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 125px;">Choose Image</button>
    <input name="img" type="file" accept="image/*" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <input type="file" id="browse" name="fileupload" style="display: none" onChange="Handlechange();"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="filename" readonly="true"/>
 <input type="button" value="Upload MB" id="fakeBrowse" onclick="HandleBrowseClick();"/>
 </body>
 <script>
 function HandleBrowseClick()
 {
   var fileinput = document.getElementById("browse");
   fileinput.click();
 }

function Handlechange()
{
 var fileinput = document.getElementById("browse");
 var textinput = document.getElementById("filename");
 textinput.value = fileinput.value;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: after uploading file how i redirct user on Form?

Answer (score 0):

There's an experimental feature that does exactly what you are looking for. You can take a look at it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showOpenFilePicker